# How to calculate this improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-(ax+\frac{b}{x})^2}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to calculate this improper integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-\left(ax\ +\ b/x\right)^2}\,{\rm d}x\ {\large ?}
$$

Comment: Please refrain from using the displaystyle mode in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left( ax + \frac{b}{x} \right)^{2}} \, dx = e^{-4ab} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left( ax - \frac{b}{x} \right)^{2}} \, dx. $$

This shows that it suffices to consider the integral on the right-hand side. Associated to this we consider a more general situation. Let assume $a > 0, b > 0$ and $f$ is an integrable *even* function. With the substitution

$$ x = \frac{b}{at} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad dx = -\frac{b}{at^2} \, dt, $$

we obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f\left( ax - \frac{b}{x} \right) \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b}{at^2} f\left( at - \frac{b}{t} \right) \, dt. $$

Thus if we denote this common value by $I$, then

\begin{align*}
2aI
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( a + \frac{b}{x^2} \right) f\left( ax - \frac{b}{x} \right) \, dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f (u) \, du,
\end{align*}

where we used the substitution

$$ u = ax - \frac{b}{x}, \quad du = \left( a + \frac{b}{x^2} \right) \, dx. $$

Therefore we obtain the following identity.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f\left( ax - \frac{b}{x} \right) \, dx = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f (x) \, dx $$

This gives us

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left( ax + \frac{b}{x} \right)^{2}} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}  e^{-4ab}. $$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{ax\ +\ b/x}^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\Large\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{ax\ +\ b/x}^{2}}\,\dd x}\ =\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-ab\bracks{\root{a \over b}x\ + \root{b \over a}\,{1 \over x}}^{2}}
\,\dd x}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ \root{a \over b}x \equiv \expo{\theta}}}
\\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-4ab\cosh^{2}\pars{\theta}}
\root{b \over a}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=\root{b \over a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-4ab\bracks{\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}
\bracks{\cosh{\theta} + \sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=2\root{b \over a}\expo{-4ab}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-4ab\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}\cosh{\theta}\,\dd\theta}
^{\ds{2\root{ab}\sinh\pars{\theta} \equiv t}}
\\[3mm]&=2\root{b \over a}\expo{-4ab}\,{1 \over 2\root{ab}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-t^{2}}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\root{\pi} \over 2}}\
=\ \color{#66f}{\Large{\root{\pi} \over 2a}\,\expo{-4ab}}
\end{align}